# Конструктор и Коллекции в Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Почему то в конструкторе через this не получается узнать данные об объекте, например:
User.php

```
...
protected $fillable = ['email', 'password']
public function __constuct() {
         var_dump($this->email);
         var_dump($this->getAttribute('email'));
}
...
Route.php
...
Route('test', function() {
         User::all();
})
...
```

Получаем:
NullNullNullNullNullNullNullNullNullNullNullNull...

Comment: Почему в email что-то должно быть?

Comment: а почему не должно? `Route::any('test', function() {
    $users = \App\User::all();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo $user->email."<br>";
    }
});`                                                                                                                       kkunde@gmail.com
wolff.britney@schmidt.com
oquigley@dubuque.biz
eloisa.ortiz@hotmail.com
graham.jedediah@hotmail.com
damore.ryley@borer.com
hodkiewicz.derek@reichel.com
aratke@hotmail.com
kacie.reichert@gmail.com
tbreitenberg@hotmail.com

Comment: Потому что из вашего кода непонятно, какой воркфлоу происходит, а специально выделенных людей по ларавелю у нас нет. Тем не менее, вы пытаетесь что-то достать в конструкторе, который выполняется сразу после создания объекта, то есть, по факту, он вызывается оператором new, и весь внешний код еще не может быть исполнен.

Comment: Я вызываю родительской конструктор, просто здесь не указал, и по логике объект должен хранить уже все данные

Comment: А вы уверены, что это заполнение в конструкторе делается?

Comment: если не в конструкторе, то где?

Comment: Не знаю, я не спец по ларавелю, но если вы сделаете реверс-инжениринг этого функционала, то получите ответы на все вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Вы, случаем, не забыли `parent::__construct()` ?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу, вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением, а когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Вполне возможно, что это и есть ответ. @unusedbrain, предлагаю вам опубликовать полный отрывок кода, в котором на нужном месте будет это выражение.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, является. Хватит придираться к вопросительным формулировкам.